# Python: Calculate the Gradient of a 3D grid

Tags: python, numpy, grid, gradient

I have a cube of particles which I've projected onto a 2D grid, Projecting the particles onto the grid by a clouds in cells and weighting them by a scalar.

I would then like the gradient of the scalar at every grid point. In 2D I am doing this using `np.gradient` and I get two arrays with the gradient in the x and y directions:

```
gradx, grady = np.gradient(grid)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can generalize this to 3 Dimensions? The Clouds in Cells in 3D is fine but I am then left with a grid with the shape (700, 700, 700).

As far as I can see `np.gradient` can't deal with this?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Does this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082148/calculating-gradient-in-3d ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Numpy documentation indicates that `gradient` works for any dimensions:

> `numpy.gradient(f, *varargs)`
>
> *Return the gradient of an N-dimensional array.*
>
> The gradient is computed using central differences in the interior and
>   first differences at the boundaries. The returned gradient hence has
>   the same shape as the input array.
>
> **Parameters :**
>
> `f: array_like.` An N-dimensional array containing samples
>   of a scalar function.
>
> `*varargs:` 0, 1, or N scalars specifying the sample distances in each direction, that is: dx, dy, dz, ... The default distance is 1.
>
> **Returns :**
>
> `g: ndarray.`  N arrays of
>   the same shape as f giving the derivative of f with respect to each
>   dimension.

Seems like you should be able to extend your 2-dimensional code to 3D like you would expect.

Comment: @japreiss, if I pass in an array with shape (100,3) to gradient, I get two arrays back, while I expect three. Do you know what those two arrays represent?

Comment: @duhaime, I'm sure you've long figured this out, but for future travellers,  a (100,3) array is 2D array so it returns two arrays - one is the gradient at all points in your input array with respect to the first axis (i.e. over rows), and the second is the gradient with respect to the second axis (i.e. over columns).  For N dimensional arrays, you get back N arrays, each containing the gradient at all points with respect to one of the N axes.